# Is a machine-readable VMS executable file format description available?

Tags: vax, vms

I have a few dusty old VAX VMS executable files I want to tease apart. I just can't seem to find a decent description of the file format. The best I've got is the "VAX/VMS internals Student Workbook", but I'd like something more authoritative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some definitions in [`freevms-0_3_15.gz`](http://fossies.org/linux/privat/old/freevms-0_3_15.tgz/), in particular `ihddef.h` for the header and `isddef.h` for the sections. There is also some code which uses those structs to parse the executables:

```
  struct _isd * section=(unsigned long)buffer+ehdr32->ihd$w_size;

  long symtab=0, symtabsize=0, symtabvbn=0, symstr=0, symstrsize=0, symstrvbn=0;

  while (section<(buffer+512*ehdr32->ihd$b_hdrblkcnt)) {
    if (section->isd$w_size==0)
      break;
    if (section->isd$w_size==0xffffffff) {
      int no=((unsigned long)section-(unsigned long)buffer)>>9;
      section=buffer+512*(no+1);
      continue;
    }
    if (debug->ihs$l_dstvbn==section->isd$l_vbn) {
      symtab=section->isd$v_vpn<<12;
      symtabvbn=debug->ihs$l_dstvbn;
      symtabsize=section->isd$w_pagcnt;
    }

    if (debug->ihs$l_dmtvbn==section->isd$l_vbn) {
      symstr=section->isd$v_vpn<<12;
      symstrvbn=debug->ihs$l_dmtvbn;
      symstrsize=section->isd$w_pagcnt;
    }

    section=(unsigned long)section+section->isd$w_size;
  }
```